# How to create application links

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash, air, adobe

I'm currently using the Adobe AIR platform. I make applications with Adobe Flash Professional CS6. I was wondering how can I make special links that connect to the app. I mean something like Skype links:

> skype:echo123?call

If it can't be created with AIR, please tell me how to create it in C# or other languages.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, I'd say there's not a clear cut answer to your question. It can be done in various ways. It revolves around creating your own "routing" mechanism, or your own "protocol" mechanism for your API or application.

For example, for each "action" in your application you could make such a protocol. Say  "File Open".. could become "app:fileopen:filename"..
You mentioned skype, but for example spotify has this method as well..

How you implement is something entirely different, and you'd need to consider following questions:

1. What benefits will it have? Why are you going to use it?
2. Should it be applicable inside the application only (e.g. browsing, or giving it through with command line arguments)? Or should it be used inside a browser as well?

Basically it will involve:

1. Schetsing a good protocol / routing schema for your API/application.
2. Implementing a framework (in whatever language) to support your routing mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! :) I'll now google some things and I hope I'll find what I'm looking for. Btw I wanted to create a game with the AIR platform. It was going to add a link to the game's website that could start the actual game.